# How can I install OpenCV 3.2.0 in Ubuntu 16.10 when it says sys/videoio.h is missing?

Tags: video, compiling, 16.10, cmake, opencv

I'm following this tutorial http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/ to install OpenCV. I'm trying to install OpenCV 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.10.

After I enter

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I'm getting the following error below:

```
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_1451c/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1451c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1451c.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/soubriquet/3rdparty/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1451c.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1451c.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /home/soubriquet/3rdparty/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/home/soubriquet/3rdparty/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/videoio.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/cmTC_1451c.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1451c.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_1451c.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/soubriquet/3rdparty/opencv-3.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_1451c/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_1451c/fast] Error 2
```

Seems like a lot of people are having this issue, but have not been able to resolve it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be an issue that should be addressed by the devs.

Comment: It looks like suggestions for fixing this problem are given in comments on that tutorial. What happens when you try them? One of the comments mentioned [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/742180). Does that help? I recommend you [edit] your question with details about all the proposed fixes and either why they appear not to apply to your situation or what happened (in detail) when you tried them. I have no handy 16.10 box for this right now but built on 16.04; the `cmake` step succeeded. Since I don't have `videoio.h` on my system, this seems to be a problem with the build configuration.